# Keep process running in background after dismissing screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm playing around with Flutter and Dart and I wanted to build an app which has a timer that starts running upon opening the page (`TimerPage`). I would also like for it to keep running in the background after leaving the page so that the counter won't stop until I cancel it manually.

I created a microversion to better show what I am trying to achieve. After pressing the button "Start timer" we navigate to the `TimerPage` where it automatically starts counting up the seconds. After going back and starting the timer again, it is back to 0, whereas I am trying to achieve that it keeps running in the background.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const TimerPage(title: 'TimerPage'),
                    ));
              },
              child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text('Start timer')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TimerPageState();
}

class _TimerPageState extends State<TimerPage> {
  Timer? timer;
  int seconds = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (timer) {
        setState(() {
          seconds++;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text('$seconds Seconds passed'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                timer?.cancel();
              },
              child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text('Stop timer'))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer?.cancel();
  }
}
```

I understand that Flutter does not support multi-threading, and one probable way of achieving this would be to use Isolates, but I was not able to get it to run unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

So As much I understand, you want to have a sticky notification when the Flutter Application goes into the background.
The Timer would keep running in the background even if the app is closed/dismissed from the foreground.

For that, you can use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service_enhanced) to get the timer to keep working in the background notification. Once you click on the notification it will redirect to the timer page.

For Example:

in main.dart

```
FlutterBackgroundService.initialize(onServiceStart);
```

in service of Timer.

```
onServiceStart(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  Timer timer;
  service.onDataReceived.listen((event){
     if (event["action"] == "startTimer"){
         timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(second: 1), (t){
                          print("tick");
                       });
     }

     if (event["action"] == "stopTimer" && timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        print("timer has stopped");
     }
  });
}
```

on TimerPage

```
FlutterBackgroundService().sendData({"action": "startTimer"});
FlutterBackgroundService().sendData({"action": "stopTimer"});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I was not able to completely replicate your proposed code since the syntax has changed quite dramatically for that plugin recently.

On the other hand, I used a different plugin https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer which has a neat solution to my problem in their issues, which you can find here: https://github.com/hukusuke1007/stop_watch_timer/issues/34